# smart contract for fair exchange

Tags: solidity, contract-design, ether

Question: Is it possible to create a smart contract for fair exchange and investment: user1 sends ether to a smart contract which will multiply the amount by 2 and send it to user2. When user2 receives ether multiplied by 2, he should send some of these ether to user1.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't operate with more ether than you have.

If you have for example 1 ETH sent in the transaction, and let's say the contract balance before = 0, that means that user2 can't receive more than 1 ETH.

Comment: Ok, so you're assuming that your contract has 3 ETH on itself?